# The component metadata for "Script Component could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component.The PerformUpgrade method failed

Tags: sql, ssis

We have shifted Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 packges to microsoft Visual Studio 2015 ,
we have build deployed at our Dev server and are running perfectly fine,
but as we have shifted our code from Dev Server to Uat Server it is throwing as error.

Error Description:

> The component metadata for "Script Component,clsid {4F885D04-B578-47B7-94A0-DE9C7DA25EE2}" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component.The PerformUpgrade method failed.

Both UAT and DEV environments are same,but still we are facing this issue.
We have builed .ISPAC file from Dev server and deployed at UAT server.
Things which we have tried are:

1. we have changed targetversion from 2016 to 2014 in VS( using from references of blogs ) and build , deployed at UAT , but it didn't work.We assumed lower version should work in higher versions.
2. We have recreated script component , build , deployed again at UAT , but no luck.
   Please suggest solution to this.

Comment: Open the script task in Visual Studio and it will update itself. And then redeploy it. This is all I needed to do when upgrading from 2008 to 2012.

Comment: Did you mean that you opened script component in 2012 version ?

Comment: yes. open in 2012 (in your case the new 2015 VS). For some reason the script tasks and components did not migrate properly but will once you go into the code.

Comment: Thanks KeithL. That was a great help :)